# Can't with String to Date convert

Tags: java, android, string, date

I have string looks like: `Sun, 27-Oct-2013 11:31:31 GMT`
for make it a little simpler i do:

```
if (s.length() > 10)
   s = s.substring(5, s.length() - 4);
```

after that

`s = " 27-Oct-2013 11:31:31"`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date timestamp = null;

 try {
   timestamp = formatter.parse(s.trim());
 } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

It catch exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "27-Oct-2013 11:31:31"`

Comment: you should try to make it simpler to find the error - try using only string 27-Oct-2013 and format dd-MMMM-yyyy and the same for time part

Comment: I tried your code and no error happen

Comment: Same for me - no exception thrown

Comment: Same for me- no exception is thrown at all. No Locale.US usage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should specify a locale where months are spelled in english for your formatter, otherwise it will use your default locale.

> `SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)`
>   Constructs a new`SimpleDateFormat`using the specified non-localized
>   pattern and the`DateFormatSymbols`and`Calendar`for the user's default
>   locale.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
```

Comment: +1. And given that the timezone of the string is GMT, the timezone should also be set to GMT on the SimpleDateFormat.